# How can I check if my object just stopped rotating this frame?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateRandom : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.naviRotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,100);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I set the flag to true and false in another script.
And here I want that each time the transform stops spinning, it should revert to looking forward once.

But since I wrote `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` in the Update method, it will try to go back to facing forward every frame. I want it to do it only once each time it stops spinning.

Comment: It appears that you have a variable `toRotate` which tells you whether or not the object is "spinning". Where and how do you set that variable?

Comment: @Philipp Updated my question with how it is now.

Comment: I'd advise against doing any checks on Euler angles. (±y•360°, ±p•360°, ±r•360°), (180, 180, 180), etc. all represent the same orientation as (0, 0, 0). So comparing for a specific number can often land you in trouble. In general you might instead want to compare orientation quaternions, or which direction transform.up is pointing, etc. Here though, it looks like you don't want to compare orientations at all. You want to find out whether `naviRotate` *was* true last frame, to clear the rotation once when it becomes false and not repeatedly every frame it remains false. Is that accurate?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, you right it's accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the other script contains the information whether the object is currently rotating or not, then it can also contain the information whether it just stopped rotating. You are not saying how that other script works exactly, but I would assume it determines the state in its update method. In that case you could modify the update method like this:

```
void Update() {
       justStoppedRotating = false; 
       if (naviRotate && /* condition occured which stops rotating */) {
             naviRotate = false;
             justStoppedRotating = true; 
       }
}
```

The variable `justStoppedRotating` will only be true on those updates where the script changes from `naviRotate == true` to `naviRotate == false`.

You can then rewrite the Update-method of RotateRandom like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.naviRotate)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 10000f * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.justStoppedRotating)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

---

Alternative solution: If you can't or don't want to change the `FPEInteractionManagerScript`, then you could have the `RotateRandom` script remember the previous state in its own private variable:

```
public class RotateRandom : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool previousNaviRotate;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.naviRotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 10000f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (previousNaviRotate == true)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }

        previousNaviRotate = Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.naviRotate;
    }
}
```

---

By the way: I took the liberty to apply the `Time.deltaTime` factor to the rotation speed. You don't want your objects to rotate with different speeds depending on the speed of the user's machine.